# How to make parent's div height auto increment depending on its children' maximum height?

Tags: css

How to make parent's div height auto increment depending on its children' maximum height?

```
<div class="parent-div">
   <div class="upper">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
   </div>
   <div class="lower"></div>
</div>
```

In this example, I have several span tag inside upper div tag, and I want the height of upper increases depending on the sum height of its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess: you floated the children as columns, and now you're asking the age-old "how do i clearfix?!?" question.

If that's the case:

```
.upper
{
  float: left;
  width: {some value here};
}

.lower
{
  clear: both;
}
```

Of course, I'm not a mind-reader, so more details would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You do nothing. What you are asking for is the default behaviour of these elements.

If they don't do that already, it's because you have set a style on them that prevents their default behaviour. You would have to identify which style setting it is that does that, and remove it.

Comment: Not sure why, if I don't set height value, that upper div doesn't appear in firefox.

Comment: @user69652: You are currently the only one who can know how you have styled the elements, as only you have access to all the code. If you post the CSS that affects the elements, others might be able to tell what's causing this.